# regular expression javascripy

Tags: javascript, regex

What can be a valid regex for a password that contains at least 8 characters in which there should be one upper-case,one lower-case and one number?

Comment: Password validation is a question asked about 329,000 times on SO, Welcome to StackOverflow !.

Comment: You may find [Reference - Password Validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48345922/reference-password-validation) relevant. Password rules are old.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a regular expression for a string with at least 8 characters, one upper-case, one lower-case and one number.

`^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)[a-zA-Z\d]{8,}$`